# Django 1.9 with CORS dumping data: "corsheaders_corsmodel" does not exist

Tags: django, postgresql, django-migrations, django-1.9

I'm developing a Django (1.9) Rest backend and AngularJS frontend with Cross-site referencing. While attempting to execute a `./manage.py dumpdata` command, it throws the following exception:

```
$ python manage.py dumpdata -o dev/dumpdata.json
CommandError: Unable to serialize database: relation 
"corsheaders_corsmodel" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT COUNT(*) AS "__count" FROM "corsheaders_corsmodel"
```

Any idea how to handle?

Comment: Do you have the current version of corsheaders installed?

Comment: django-cors-headers==1.1.0

Comment: Could you please select a correct answer to this question? It seems @myk-willis has the right one.

Answer (score 24):

I had this same problem, and resolved it by invoking `python manage.py makemigrations` specifically for the `corsheaders` app:

```
$ python manage.py makemigrations corsheaders
$ python manage.py migrate
```

I think what happened in my case was that, after an upgrade from Django 1.8 to 1.9, the initial migration was never applied when I updated my DB.

I tracked it down by noticing that the `corsheaders` app was not listed in the `Apply all migrations` output of `python manage.py migrate`:

```
$ python manage.py migrate
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: sessions, admin, xyz, auth, contenttypes
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.
```

Yet running a manual migration for `corsheaders` actually creates the initial migration:

```
$ python manage.py makemigrations corsheaders
Migrations for 'corsheaders':
  0001_initial.py:
    - Create model CorsModel
```

After having done that, a `migrate` does show `corsheaders` in the output, and successfully applies the migration as expected:

```
$ python manage.py migrate
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: corsheaders, sessions, admin, xyz, auth, contenttypes
Running migrations:
  Rendering model states... DONE
  Applying corsheaders.0001_initial... OK
```

Answer (score 2):

If corsheaders_corsmodel table does not exist, then there's no data to dump.
So you can just run:

```
$python manage.py dumpdata --exclude=corsheaders
```

I had the same problem and I solve it this way.